# Is it possible to use document.querySelector in Invoke-WebRequest in powershell 3.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, selectors-api

I'm downloading website with such command:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

Is it possible to use [querySelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [querySelectorAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288532%28v=vs.85%29) to find certain elements? I know I can use `$response.ParsedHtml.all` and filter those, but I want to use more sophisticated query and I don't see anything in `$response.ParsedHtml.documentElement`.

I'm using powershell 3 RC.

Comment: It does exist now!

Answer (score 2):

I use the method getElementsByTagName.  I'm not sure if that will work for you.  Here's how I get the images from the page, using your code above:

```
$response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Other methods exist for class name or ID.  Use `$response.ParsedHtml | gm -MemberType Method` for more options.